# Getting RID and SID using XMPP4r

Tags: ruby, xmpp4r

I'm having problems in how to get the SID and the RID after I connect to my jabber server using the XMPP4r gem. I can connect successfully and I just need the SID and RID to pass it to the javascript.

I've searched the docs [here](http://home.gna.org/xmpp4r/rdoc/) but it hasn't helped me much.

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone else would encounter the same roadblock in the future, I solved this by accessing the instance variables directly like so:

First, require the httpbinding client, instead of client

```
require 'xmpp4r/httpbinding/client'
```

then connect by doing

```
@client = Jabber::HTTPBinding::Client.new("your_jabber_id_with/resource")
@client.connect("your_bosh_url")
@client.auth("your_jabber_password")
```

The instance variables are @http_sid and @http_rid, and since they are not accessible I did

```
sid = @client.instance_variable_get("@http_sid")
rid = @client.instance_variable_get("@http_rid")
```

Then I stored those variables in my session so that I can use them on my Strophe.js client.

Comment: Fails with : HTTP request path is empty :S

Comment: Same error here... Please tell us how did you solve the HTTP request path empty issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it for all the Openfire Users :

```
require 'xmpp4r'
require 'xmpp4r/httpbinding/client'



class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index

    Jabber::debug = true
    @client = Jabber::HTTPBinding::Client.new('sankalpsingha@sankalpmacbook') # This is the JID
    @client.connect('http://localhost:7070/http-bind/') # This is the bosh address
    @client.auth('sankalp') # This is the password 
    @sid = @client.instance_variable_get('@http_sid')
    @rid = @client.instance_variable_get('@http_rid')


  end
end
```